# How to replace a line in SQL statement using sed or any other command?

Tags: shell

We have several `.sql` files and some of them have a `where` clause to get a selective data. I would like to parameterize  values that will be passed onto a `select` statement.

For example:

file 1:

```
select eid,deptid,name from employee where deptid = 25;
```

file 2:

```
select studentname,studentid from student;
```

file 3:

```
select  staff,deptid,name from staff,dept where dept.id = staff.deptid
and deptid =25
```

I need to do the following things:

1. Read all listed files. (i.e. file 1,2 and 3)
2. check if there is a filter condition on `deptid`
3. If exists, replace that variable using parameter passed as a input.

Say if I execute the below script then all `deptid` should get replaced by 28

```
readsqlfile.sh 28
```

Comment: Have you tried to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: Do you really want to replace column name with argument or value of column with argument?

Answer (score 0):

`for i in file1 file2 file3 fileX; do sed -i "s/deptid/${INPUT}/g" $i; done`

This will replace all occurences of `deptid` by the value inside `INPUT` variable in `file1 file2 file3 fileX`

Comment: Thank you Zelnes . It worked for me ... I used below command.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in file replacement:

```
ishan@shurima:/tmp$ cat 1
select eid,deptid,name from employee where deptid = 25;
ishan@shurima:/tmp$ sed -i 's/where deptid/where 28/g' ./1
ishan@shurima:/tmp$ cat 1
select eid,deptid,name from employee where 28 = 25;
ishan@shurima:/tmp$
```

This will only change the condition not every occurance of deptid.